# Is it possible to check which browser a user is using through php? And if yes proceed to a redirect if a specific browser is found

Tags: php, html

To make it clearer I want to redirect the users who are using Internet Explorer 6 to 8 from index.php to ie.php

I am using the following php code:

```
 <?php


        $url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);


           header( 'Location: http://'.$url.'' ) ;  


        ?>
```

Which will be the if statement in order to identify the user's browser and if it is IE6 to 8 the code to proceed with the redirect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] , the user agent is a string which contains some details like browser version, os, language etc...

Comment: How exactly am I using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] in an if statement in order to proceed with the redirect though?

Comment: you should analyze the string, u can do that with strstr(). check what string appear in case the user using IE, and search that string in the user agent.if the string was found,apparently he use IE, and u can redirect him. GL bro.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.useful.php - Instead of the echo in example #2 and #3 you can do a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

How about: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Just put your `if` where you want.

```
<?php
function getBrowser()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
}

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
echo $yourbrowser;
?>
```